# How to read error running Console Application from Delphi Code using PeekNamedPipe()

Tags: delphi, console-application

I have Delphi code which is used to run Java.exe from JAVA_HOME with a given set of parameters. This is achieved through CreateProcess() by passing Command Line command to it. For a particualr set of input parameters, this gives me an error which says "Could not create Java Virtual Machine". I need to get this through PeekNamedPipe() into Delphi code and display it in the application. How can I achieve this?
The Delphi code looks like this:

```
  begin
  securityAttr.nlength := SizeOf(TSecurityAttributes);
  securityAttr.binherithandle := true;
  securityAttr.lpsecuritydescriptor := nil;

  if CreatePipe (readPipe, writePipe, @securityAttr, 0) then
  begin

  buffer  := AllocMem(READ_BUFFER + 1);
  FillChar(startInfo, Sizeof(startInfo), #0);
  startInfo.cb          := SizeOf(startInfo);
  startInfo.hStdOutput  := writePipe;
  startInfo.hStdInput   := readPipe;
  startInfo.dwFlags     := STARTF_USESTDHANDLES + STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
  startInfo.wShowWindow := SW_HIDE;

  if SearchPath(nil, PChar(consoleApp), '.exe', SizeOf(consoleAppBuf), consoleAppBuf, exeName) = 0 then
  raise EInOutError.CreateFmt('Could not find file %s', [consoleApp]);

FmtStr(commandLine, '"%s" %s', [consoleAppBuf, parameters]);

if CreateProcess(nil, PChar(commandLine), nil, nil, true, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, nil, nil, startInfo, processInfo) then
begin

  totalBytesRead := 0;

  repeat        
    exitCode := WaitForSingleObject(ProcessInfo.hProcess, 100);
    Application.ProcessMessages;

    if (PeekNamedPipe(readPipe, @buffer[totalBytesRead],
                         READ_BUFFER, @bytesRead,
                         @totalBytesAvail, @bytesLeftThisMessage)) then
    begin

      if (bytesRead > 0) then
        ReadFile(readPipe, buffer[totalBytesRead], bytesRead, bytesRead, nil);

      totalBytesRead := totalBytesRead + bytesRead;

    end;

  until (exitCode <> WAIT_TIMEOUT);

  GetExitCodeProcess(ProcessInfo.hProcess, result);

  buffer[totalBytesRead]:= #0;
  OemToChar(buffer, buffer);
  output.Text := output.Text + StrPas(buffer);

  FreeMem(buffer);
  CloseHandle(processInfo.hProcess);
  CloseHandle(processInfo.hThread);
  CloseHandle(readPipe);
  CloseHandle(writePipe);

end
else
  RaiseLastWin32Error;

end;
```

How can I read the error thrown by java.exe?

Comment: Why have you connected the standard input/output of the process with the same pipe? What are you trying to achieve by doing that? Or are you just trying with pipes pretty much at random? Does this code do anything at all? Where does the output from the process go? stdout or stderr?

Comment: This is a snippet from the delphi function to run console application. It will createProcess() for the command line parameter and read the result of the process. Output of the process goes into the input buffer of PeekNamedPipe. This however only happens when the java.exe runs successfully without any errors. I need to capture the error thrown while running java.exe

Comment: Please my comment again. Why do you connect both ends of the same pipe to the same process standard handles?

Comment: You are redirecting stdout of child process to stdin of child process. Minor: you do not have to poll pipe handle, it will be signaled when data available.

Comment: Not sure how this works. I am assuming that this a ReadPipe is created and PeekNamedPipe() is to read the output from the console application output.

Comment: How it works is that you can write to the write end and read from the read end. What goes in the write end comes out of the read end. You want to put the write end of your pipe on stdout and/or stderr. And then read from the read end. That's how you get hold of the output from the program. As for the input, that should be either a different pipe if you want to pipe stuff in, or nothing at all to inherit the calling process standard in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a mistake to connect both ends of the same pipe to the input and output of the same process. You are feeding the output of the process back into its input. Leave `hStdInput` as `NULL`.

You also play fast and loose with error checking, and run the risk of leaking handles because you don't use `finally` blocks. And I'm not keen on the busy loop. Or the call to `ProcessMessages`.

Leaving that all aside, the likely reason for you not reading errors is that they go to stderr. Connect the write end of your pipe to stderr, as well as to stdout:

```
startInfo.hStdOutput  := writePipe;
startInfo.hStdError  := writePipe;
```

Comment: I read up a little more on the concept of using NamedPipe with process. Realized it is a mistake to connect both ends of a pipe to i/p and o/p of a process. Corrected that. Also, added hStdError to my startInfo and it worked! Thanks